# Mongo groupby three fields, get unique count for one field

Tags: mongodb

I have records stored in my collection as follows:

```
{
       "sessionId" : "f960e3db-838c-42aa-95ce-a807096f7036",
       "date" : "12-02-2020",
       "hour" : "13",
       "month" : "02",
       "time" : "13:46:50",
       "weekDay" : "Wednesday",
}
```

**I want to group the above records by 'date', 'hour', getting the number of unique'sessionId' per hour.** Something like below:

```
{
"12-02-2020": {
    00: 23,//hour:unique number of sessions in that hour
    01: 3,
    04: 33,
    05: 0,
    10: 1
 },
"13-02-2020": {
    00: 2,//hour:unique number of sessions in that hour
    03: 33,
    09: 23,
    05: 6,
    10: 1
 }
}
```

**Can anyone please formulate the query for the above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often a challenge when you desire dynamic field names and arrays, I found this solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   // group by hour
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { date: "$date", hour: "$hour" },
         sessions: { $addToSet: "$sessionId" }
      }
   },
   // count the sessions
   { $set: { sessions: { $size: "$sessions" } } },
   // group by day
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$_id.date",
         hour: { $push: "$_id.hour" },
         sessions: { $push: "$sessions" }
      }
   },
   // transform result
   { $set: { data: { $range: [0, { $size: "$hour" }] } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $map: {
               input: "$data",
               as: "idx",
               in: {
                  k: { $arrayElemAt: ["$hour", "$$idx"] },
                  v: { $arrayElemAt: ["$sessions", "$$idx"] }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // transform day and hour values
   { $set: { v: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } },
   { $project: { data: { k: "$_id", v: "$v" } } },
   { $set: { data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rwXnQUa3Gfb)

Comment: In Mongo version 4.0.2, I'm getting the following error:

Error:
Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'",
 "code" : 40324,
 "codeName" : "Location40324"
} :

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: `$set` is new in Mongo 4.2, try `$addFields`

Comment: Wish I could give more upvotes to your comment. You saved my life man! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** group based on session & date & hour to get unique docs based on session */
  { $group: { _id: { session: "$sessionId", date: "$date", hour: "$hour" } } },
  /** group on date & hour & count no.of docs */
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { date: "$_id.date", hour: "$_id.hour" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  /** transform into entire data of each doc into data field with converting ['k':k..., 'v':v...] into {k,v} */
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [
            {
              k: "$_id.date",
              v: { $arrayToObject: [[{ k: "$_id.hour", v: "$count" }]] }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  /** replace root of each doc with new root as data */
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_znqTtHW1pC)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : By the time you're in second `group` you should be getting unique session id's